# maxle lever is very loose

Tags: wheels, axle, quick-release, through-axle

I have a Whyte T-129s and the lever on the maxle is now very loose when putting the wheels back on. It no longer holds in place - is it possible to fix this?

EDIT this is a maxle - its a thicker axle, at 15mm or 20mm up from the 9mm of a QR with a skewer.  This adds stiffness and strength.

[image]

Comment: What is a maxle?

Comment: see http://www.29ercafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/2013-Niner-Jet9-RDO-29er-maxle-rear-axle.jpg

Comment: From RockShox: "Who obsesses over the weight of their wheel axles? It’s ridiculous, right? It’s just a rod of metal bolting the wheels to your bike. But then again, Maxle Lite is a nifty thru axle system that makes your bike both lighter and stiffer. And less weight makes it easier to get your bike to do what you want. Especially when you don’t need to bring tools to remove it, front or rear. And that extra stiffness gives you the precision to hit your lines no matter how burly. So maybe that obsession isn’t so ridiculous after all." (https://www.sram.com/rockshox/technologies/maxle-lite)

Comment: I know this is asking the obvious but did you tighten the nut on the other end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think all Maxle's are the same, but I've had two different types and each could be tightened in a slightly different way.  With one (I believe an older design) there is a 2.5mm hex bolt on the lever end which you can tighten/loosen to affect how tight the lever is.

See an example of this here:

http://www.bike-manual.com/brands/trek/om/assets/pdfs/09sram_maxle_cengdfjnp.pdf

On the other, the lever could be tightened by pushing the end in and twisting.

Explained in this article about half way down:

http://www.bikemag.com/gear/news-rockshoxs-pike-is-back/

Comment: Thanks! Tightening the hex bolt was the solution for my Rockshox maxle.

Comment: According to the Maxle Lite flyer in the first URL above the required hex wrench is 2.5 mm. Following the directions in the flyer resulted in a tight cam clamp that worked as it did when the bike came from the bike shop.

Comment: You're right, 6mm would be pretty big.  Updated the answer to reflect this.